# I can't deploy an AngularJS app to heroku

Tags: angularjs, build, gruntjs, src

When I do 'grunt build' I get the following message: Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task

> Destination build/blog.min.js not written because src files were empty.
>
> No files created.
>
> Done.

I think something is wrong with my folder structure but I am not sure if that is the issue. Here is the layout of my folder structure with the package.json and displayed:

[image: package.json and gruntfile]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your minification task is failing because it can't find the file you're trying to minify.

You should verify in your `gruntfile.js` that the `src` file for `uglify:build`  is a file that actually exists.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Ben. I have changed it to a file that does exist and I am now getting the following: Warning: Task "build" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
Pablos-MacBook-Pro:suggestion_box3 Pablo$ grunt --force
Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
File app.min.js created: 356 B → 305 B
>> 1 file created.
Done.

Comment: @PabloBolañosCacho you need to edit your question and post your `gruntfile.js` so I can help.

Answer (score 0):

[Grunt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwBwh.png)

I have uploaded gruntfile.js and app.js files.